# how can I write a test case to compare infinity value?

Tags: java, java-8, double

how can I write a test case to compare infinity value. Example 10/0.0 results infinity how can i write following for it

```
assertThat(<**what will be here?**>).isCloseTo(10/0.0);
```

Comment: Is your intention to catch a divide-by-zero? In what cases are you expecting an infinite value?

Comment: Nothing "isCloseTo" infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
assertTrue(Double.isInfinite(10/0.0))
```

Comment: Perfect answer +1 (except for that double set of parentheses). Well, and the fact that it's the `<**what will be here?**>` that needs to be tested. ;-)

Comment: not perfect because this is true also for Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY.
Test for equality with deviation is also odd.

Comment: What about assertTrue(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY == 10/0.0)? 
By the way for 10/(-0.0) it is the negative infinite value.